# ACF repeater field not opening modal when inserting counter

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

Tried several approaches but none of them work and can´t figure out what else to do. As part of a team page I have a repeater field with 4 subfields —image, title(caption),link(to trigger modal) and details(modal text content)— where some should open a modal with extra info when clicked. The modal works fine but when I try to insert a counter in the code to open the corresponding subfield for each team member, it stops working and nothing opens.

Here´s the bit of code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<div class="team-block w4 clear" >                      
    <?php 
        if( have_rows('team_member') ): 
            $counter = 1;
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php 
            while( have_rows('team_member') ): the_row();

            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('team_member_image');
            $title = get_sub_field('team_member_title');
            $link = get_sub_field('link_to_details');
            $details = get_sub_field('team_member_details');
        ?>
        <li class="team-member-box">
            <?php if( $link ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <img class="team-member-image" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
            <?php 
                echo $title; 
                if( $link ): 
            ?>
                </a>                    
            <?php 
                endif;  
                if( $link ): 
            ?>
                <div class="remodal team-member-details" data-remodal-id="modal<?php echo $counter;?>">
                    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
                    <h3>Qualifications</h3>                      
                    <p><?php echo $details; ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>                 
        </li>
        <?php 
            $counter++; 
            endwhile; 
        ?>                  
    </ul>                                                                   
    <?php endif; ?>                     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
<a href="#modal1">Modal №1</a>
<a href="#modal2">Modal №2</a>
<a href="#modal3">Modal №3</a>


<div class="remodal team-member-details" data-remodal-id="modal1">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <h3>Qualifications</h3>
  <p>yeah</p>
</div>

<div class="remodal team-member-details" data-remodal-id="modal2">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <h3>Qualifications</h3>
  <p>yeah 2</p>
</div>

<div class="remodal team-member-details" data-remodal-id="modal3">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <h3>Qualifications</h3>
  <p>yeah 3</p>
</div>
```

This works as expected. When I look at your code, I assume that the click on the image shoukd trigger the modal, right? I so, try this:

```
<div class="team-block w4 clear" >

    <?php if( have_rows('team_member') ): ?>

    <?php $counter = 1; ?>


        <ul>

        <?php while( have_rows('team_member') ): the_row();

            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('team_member_image');
            $title = get_sub_field('team_member_title');
            $link = get_sub_field('link_to_details');
            $details = get_sub_field('team_member_details');

            ?>



            <li class="team-member-box">


                    <a href="modal<?php echo $counter;?>">


                <img class="team-member-image" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />

                <?php echo $title; ?>

                    </a>

                <?php if( $link ): ?>
                    <div class="remodal team-member-details" data-remodal-id="modal<?php echo $counter;?>">
                      <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
                      <h3>Qualifications</h3>                        
                      <p><?php echo $details; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </li>

        <?php $counter++; ?>    

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I am not sure if this is right (dunno what to do with the $link var) but this should work.

Comment: Works like a charm after adding # to the href “modal”. Also I needed to leave the if( $link ) bits there, since I only want a modal for those who has extra content to view, not all. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: glad I could help! :)